# AQGridView cells disappear when scrolling horizontally and can't lock it

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, aqgridview

I pulled AQGridView from the latest git repos based on recommendations from here.  I like it, but unfortunately when it scrolls horizontally the cell's just disappear.  Also, it locks when scrolling vertically but not horizontally.  I noticed an open issue in git for it, but it was closed with no resolution.  Has anyone gotten this to work properly from the demo's?

Thanks, Graeme.

Comment: Ok, I can lock the table (duh, I've done this before)  _gridView.directionalLockEnabled = YES;  But the icons still dissapear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/RadhikaS/AQGridView/tree/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.